# Closed wallet on MultiBit, found it in AppData, but when I click "open" nothing happens

Tags: wallet, multibit

I have clicked on "close wallet" by mistake, and thought it was lost, and then found it in `C:\user\<my name>\AppData\Roaming`... but, when I click to open the wallet nothing happens.

I have saved my private keys to a USB stick, and my public address is written down (this wallet is in [MultiBit](https://multibit.org/)). I have Windows 8.

Is it possible to recover my wallet?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in v0.5.15 where if you close a wallet and then reopen it straight away the screen does not refresh. If you shut down multibit and then start it up again you should see it.